# Allowed characters for label of the Vertex in Cosmos DB

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

The question is what are allowed character for the label of the vertices in CosmosDB? Could I use these `$,-,_,~,#,@,%,^,|, ...` ascii printable characters in label of a vertex in gremlin query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I cannot find any reference to the gremlin or Cosmos DB documentation about this. However, as I've tested, As the set label is located as a value for label property for a vertex, there is no limitation on the value of the label. Hence, you can run the following in Cosmos DB without any problem:

```
 g.addV('~!@#$%^&*()_+=')
```

Also, you can set these ascii printable characters as a property name for the vertices and edges.