# Which symbols are forbidden for Gremlin vertex label name?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am stuck on searching this info. Are there any forbidden symbols for creating vertex labels in gremlin?

Especially, I am interested if label name with spaces and brackets like `g.addV("New node (1)")` is valid?

I'm using gremlin with tinkerpop and Cosmos DB

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a TinkerPop/Gremlin perspective it is best to avoid keys and labels that start with a tilda (`~`) as that prefix has special meaning in some cases. By convention it is also best to avoid "id" and "label" as key names as they are easily confused with `T.id` and `T.label`. As for CosmosDB in particular, I'm not aware of any particular character limitations on the vertex label (I base that on [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45739590/1831717) which I happened to recall coming across a while ago), however with graphs in the TinkerPop-space the general convention tends to be a simple Pascal case without special characters.